# Can I use one htaccess file to 301 redirect a list of files another domain and with files changing name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am moving a website to another domain, and at the same time I am changing the website structure and file names.
 
So each of my old files needs to be redirected to a new domain and to a different file name, often in a different folder. 
Can this be done with a single .htaccess file in which I list the old and new files? 
How would this .htaccess look?
And where to put this htaccess? Only in the root or in every folder?

Or is there another solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**A1 :** Yes you can.

**A2 :** That depends on your links (But I can assure you that if you have a lot of links, he may look like a mess).

**A3 :** Put it in the root folder is enough.